# How to specify multiple values in when using case statement in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following table

```
Id  Number  TypeOfChange
1   2X      Scope,Cost,Schedule,EVM,PA
2   3x      Scope,Cost
```

Expected output:

```
Id  Number  TypeOfChange                Scope  Cost  Schedule  EVM  PA
1   2X      Scope,Cost,Schedule,EVM,PA  X      X     X         X    X
2   3x      Scope,Cost                  X      X
```

I try the following script but its not working

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    Number,
    TypeOfChange,        
    Scope = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange = 'Scope' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END,
    Cost = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange = 'Cost' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END,
    Schedule = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange = 'Schedule' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END,
    EVM = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange = 'EVM' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END,
    PA = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange = 'PA' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END 
FROM A
```

Answer (score 5):

Use Like operator.

```
SELECT 
    Id, 
    Number,
    TypeOfChange,        
    Scope = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange Like '%Scope%' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END,
    Cost = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange Like '%Cost%' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END,
    Schedule = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange Like '%Schedule%' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END,
    EVM = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange Like '%EVM%' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END,
    PA = CASE 
        WHEN TypeOfChange Like '%PA%' THEN 'X' 
        ELSE '' END  
FROM A
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: I'd usually recommend adding additional commas at the start and end of the patterns to match and the string being searched, to avoid false positives if some items may be substrings of others (e.g. if you wouldn't want `Cost` to be flagged for a TypeOfChange value of `Abc, Scosth,Def`)

Answer (score 0):

we can try `charindex` or `patindex`

```
 SELECT 
        Id, 
        Number,
        TypeOfChange,        
        Scope = CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX('Scope',TypeOfChange)>0   THEN 'X' 
            ELSE '' END,
        Cost = CASE 
            WHEN  CHARINDEX('Cost',TypeOfChange)>0   THEN 'X'  
            ELSE '' END,
        Schedule = CASE 
            WHEN  CHARINDEX('Schedule',TypeOfChange)>0   THEN 'X' 
            ELSE '' END,
        EVM = CASE 
            WHEN  CHARINDEX('EVM',TypeOfChange)>0   THEN 'X' 
            ELSE '' END,
        PA = CASE 
               WHEN  CHARINDEX('PA',TypeOfChange)>0   THEN 'X' 
            ELSE '' END  
    FROM #AA
```

output

```
Id  Number  TypeOfChange    Scope   Cost    Schedule    EVM PA
1   2X  Scope,Cost,Schedule,EVM,PA  X   X   X   X   X
2   3x  Scope,Cost  X   X
```

Answer (score 0):

If `TypeOfChange` is a dynamic value, you may want to go the dynamic route.

```
select * into [T1] from 
(values (1, '2X', 'Scope,Cost,Schedule,EVM,PA'), (2, '3x', 'Scope,Cost'), (3, '4x', 'someOtherType')) t(Id, Number, TypeOfChange) 

--typeOfChange into column list
Declare @SQL varchar(max)  = Stuff(( 
    SELECT distinct ',' + QuoteName(LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value('.[1]','varchar(8000)'))))
    FROM ( SELECT CAST('<XMLRoot><RowData>' + REPLACE(TypeOfChange,',','</RowData><RowData>') + '</RowData></XMLRoot>' AS XML) AS x
    FROM   [T1]) t CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/XMLRoot/RowData')m(n)
    Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')

Select  @SQL = '
Select [Id],[Number], [TypeOfChange],' + @SQL + '
From (
        SELECT Id, Number, TypeOfChange, 
                LTRIM(RTRIM(m.n.value(''.[1]'',''varchar(8000)''))) AS [Type], ''X'' as Value 
                FROM (  SELECT Id, Number, TypeOfChange, CAST(''<XMLRoot><RowData>'' + REPLACE(TypeOfChange,'','',''</RowData><RowData>'') + ''</RowData></XMLRoot>'' AS XML) AS x
                        FROM   [T1]) t CROSS APPLY x.nodes(''/XMLRoot/RowData'')m(n)
     ) A
 Pivot (max(Value) For [Type] in (' + @SQL + ') ) pvt'
Exec(@SQL);
```

Alternatively you may want to define your Types in a lookup table

```
select * into [Types] from 
(values (1, 'Scope'), (2, 'Cost'), (3, 'Schedule'), (4, 'EVM'), (5, 'PA'), (6, 'someOtherType')) a (Id, TypeOfChange)
```

Then change the above *--typeOfChange into column..* block like this:

```
--typeOfChange into column list
Declare @SQL varchar(max)  = Stuff(( 
    SELECT distinct ',' + QuoteName(TypeOfChange)
    FROM [Types] 
    Order by 1 For XML Path('')),1,1,'')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, using LIKE is wrong approach. Especcialy  in cases, when one of your strings become f.e."Periscope". You will get false positives.

Try to create user defined function to split strs:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[str__split](
     @str           NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@delimiter     NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS @split TABLE(
     [str] NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO @split(
         [str]
    )
    SELECT 
        [X].[C].[value]('(./text())[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)')
    FROM 
        ( 
            SELECT 
                [X] = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' + REPLACE(@str, @delimiter, '</i><i>') + '</i>').query('.')
        )                   AS  [A] 
    CROSS APPLY 
        [X].[nodes]('i')    AS  [X]([C]);

   RETURN;

END
```

And then use query:

```
SELECT
     [t].*
    ,[Scope]        =   CASE WHEN [t2].[Scope]      IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'X' END
    ,[Cost]         =   CASE WHEN [t2].[Cost]       IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'X' END
    ,[Schedule]     =   CASE WHEN [t2].[Schedule]   IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'X' END
    ,[EVM]          =   CASE WHEN [t2].[EVM]        IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'X' END
    ,[PA]           =   CASE WHEN [t2].[PA]         IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 'X' END
FROM
    [your table]    AS [t]
OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT * FROM (SELECT [str] from [dbo].[str__split]([TypeOfChange], ','))   AS [d]
        PIVOT
        (MAX([str]) FOR [str] IN ([Scope], [Cost], [Schedule], [EVM], [PA]))        AS [piv]
    )   AS [t2]
```